# How can I use google drive api to find by whom a file was shared

Tags: google-drive-api

I know I can use the file [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions#Permission) to see with who a file was shared with, but how can use the api to find who was the user that shared the file?

Comment: In your situation, you are the owner of the file?

Comment: @Tanaike not necessarily

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `not necessarily`, can I ask you for more information? For example, it supposes that there is a Google Spreadsheet (Owner is "User A" who is not you.) First, "User A" shares the Spreadsheet with "User B". As the next step, "User B" shares the Spreadsheet with you. Under this condition, you want to know that the Spreadsheet was shared by "User B". Is my understanding correct? And, your account is included in Google Workspace? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant.  When a file is shared who did the sharing is not abaliable.

Anyone with access to the file can technically share it.   There are a few exceptions with who you can share a file to if the file is part of a domain or a group.

So there is really no way of knowing who did the sharing.

this is true with both the google drive web app and with the api.